# sidebar covers footer in internet explorer 6 and 7

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-7, footer, sidebar

i have designed a template for wordpress, the problem is that when sidebar gets longer some of it will cover the footer in internet explorer 6 and 7, the website address is : http://blog.baabak.ir (its in persian), but if you look at it in internet explorer 6,7 you will see the sidebar logo will cover the footer, for example in this page :

http://blog.baabak.ir/?page_id=141

but the website is ok in other browsers, whats the problem ?

Comment: the problem was the negative bottom margin on main content div, i removed it and it fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure to use the `clear:both;`, when you are using `float` in `CSS`

your `<div id="main_content">` shouldn't be floating.

only the sidebar should set with `float:left` if you want a right sidebar you should make `float:right`.

see this [tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0816.htm) how to make a two column liquid design.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
+ HEADER (no float)                           +
+---------------------------------------------+
+ Sidebar float:left + content (no float)     +
+---------------------------------------------+
+ footer (no float)                           +
+---------------------------------------------+
```

right now you page is like this

```
+---------------------------------------------+
+ HEADER (no float)                           +
+---------------------------------------------+
+ Sidebar float:left + content (float:right)  +
+---------------------------------------------+
+ footer (no float)                           +
+---------------------------------------------+
```

which create your problem

Comment: i have used clear but it has no effect in internet explorer 6,7

Comment: @Datis: I have added few details take a look.

Comment: i have added the clear after main_content div but not working !

Comment: @Datis: you need more then that

Comment: thnx, but if i remove float from main content , the whole page will collapse ! i think its because the direction (rtl) of my content !

Comment: @Datis: I have never played with rtl pages but I think it should work, try to make a really simple page to test the layout, or even to grab the example from my link and see how it goes with rtl.

Comment: anyway, thnx for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two columns in a div and set that to clear both like the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this still active, however since I found this easy on Google, others will as well. I completely agree with clearing the floats, that is important, however one more "issue" could arise if your sidebar is: position:absolute; or any kind of position for your sidebar, that's where the problem is.

i.e. in my case I had this:

```
#sidebar {
    margin: 120px 0 0 0;
    float: right;
    width: 235px;
    left: 733px;
}
```

the sidebar is positioned just where I wanted and it "pushes" the footer instead of overflowing it, or going under in some situations.